# Struct inheritance: implicitly public or private?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, public

I am not able isolate this error in a small sample to demonstrate here, but the even the error message is so self-contradicting that maybe one can have an idea if this is a bug or not, without testing.

I have a struct that is (presumably, publicly) deriving another one, yet clang insists this is implicitly private inheritance:

```
error: 'next' is a private member of 'base'

note: constrained by implicitly private inheritance here
struct derived_temp <key> : base <derived>
```

while g++ compiles fine. I have only changed the actual names of the classes to make messages more readable. The code looks like this:

```
template </*...*/>
struct base : //...
{
private:
    //...

public:
    template <typename I> I next(I i) const { return /*...*/; }
    //...
};

template <typename /*...*/>
struct derived_temp;

struct key { /*...*/ };

using derived = derived_temp <key>;

template <>
struct derived_temp <key> : base <derived>
{
   //...
};
```

I have tried to keep the form of the code exactly the same as in my project, only changing names and commenting out parts of it.

The error is caused by attempting to call function `next()` on a temporary object of type `derived`.

My only explanation is that this may be a bug of clang (yet, I cannot reproduce it in a small sample) that forces me to change

```
struct derived_temp <key> : base <derived>
```

to the more explicit

```
struct derived_temp <key> : public base <derived>
```

Any idea?

Comment: without knowing at least part of your `...` ellipses, we can't venture a guess... what happens if you skip the `using` and try `struct derived_temp<key>: base<derived_temp<key>>`? what are the parameters to `base` and what does it inherit from?

Comment: @Massa I understand, but after half an hour I still couldn't isolate the problem so I decided to just add `public` keyword rather than keep searching :-)

Comment: @Massa Nothing changes if skip `using`. `base` takes a single parameter to the derived class, say `D`, and it inherits from a utility class also templated on `D` that provides an overloaded method `der()` to conveniently cast the object to `D&&`, `D&`, or `const D&`. Just that.

Comment: forgot to ask: which version of clang?

Comment: @Massa clang 3.3. Unfortunately, I don't have 3.4 yet.

Comment: Not reproducible [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2823b0c45d8cb7ac). Please try to come up with a complete self-contained example.

Comment: @n.m. Yes I know, and sorry for the trouble. I thought that I may be overlooking something even though it's not reproducible, that's why I asked. I may try again some other time, or I may just leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
struct T1 {
  int x;
};

struct T2 : T1 {
  int y;
};

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
  T2 t2;
  t2.x = 3;

  return t2.x;
}
```

Building/running:

```
~ clang blah.cc -o blah; ./blah; echo $?
3
~ clang blah.cc -std=c++11 -o blah; ./blah; echo $?
3
```

In short: defaults to public inheritance.

---

I spent a little more time on this to get it closer to the OPs code; this is what I put together (please forgive the typos; I'm using an airgapped machine to test this out):

```
template <class T>
struct base {
  T x;
  template <typename I> I blah( I i ) const { return i + x.k.y; }
}

template <class T>
struct derived_temp;
struct key { int y; };
using derived = derived_temp<key>;
template <>
struct derived_temp<key> : base <derived> {
  int z;
  key k;
};

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
  derived d;

  d.x   = 1;
  d.k.y = 2;
  d.z   = 3;

  return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
~ clang --version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
~ clang++ test.cc -o test -std=c++11
```

I get two basic errors (I'm not quoting the full thing since I'd have to manually type it all):

```
test.cc:3:5: error: field has incomplete type 'derived_temp<key>'
test.cc:21:5: error: no member named 'x' in 'derived_temp<key>'
```

As I stared at this, trying to understand both your motivation/intent as well as what the errors said, it occurs to me you're attempting <s>to do circular inheritance</s> to define things in a circular fashion that may not even be possible.

Comment: and to clarify, I get the same errors I had originally when I build with clang 3.2 and 3.3.

Comment: That's a problem with your own way of defining `base`. `T` is a derived type of `base`. So you can't just have a member of type `T` inside `base`. I don't do that of course. I only use `T` to `static_cast` the `base` object e.g. to `T&` as mentioned in comments above.

Comment: See if you can make a toy example on par with what I attempted; assuming you don't end up solving it in the process, post it for us to have a look at.  Otherwise we're left guessing at things like what base derives from, what members exist, how many template parameters there are, etc.

Comment: I accidentally made some progress. `derived_temp` was originally declared as **`class`** and then the specialization defined as **`struct`**, deriving `base`. Now if I use `struct` in the declaration as well, the error disappears. That's a very clean workaround. Unfortunately, this still looks invalid and I still cannot isolate it on any toy example. It only happens in the large project.

Answer (score 0):

Something is a little off there. Structs should use public inheritance by default. Forget the templates for a moment and the using directive.

Test with the simplest code which sets up your suspected fail case:

```
struct Base
{
int i;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
};
```

Now try access i from an instance of Derived. If that works, and it should, start to add features until it has all the same kinds of components as your original code.

Right now I don't have clang to test it myself. So I'm just suggesting a way forward.

Comment: That's the problem of large projects: you can't just "add features until it has all the same kinds of components as your original code" without rewriting half the project.

Comment: It depends heavily on the kind of problem. In this case it would seem that use of the language or a language feature is causing the issue. So you probably don't need half your project rewritten, but just the kinds of relationships modeled. I suspect there is a good chance that a repro case may only involve 3 objects.

Comment: I may try again some other time. For now I tried for more than an hour without success so I made this question just in case I'm overlooking something and applied the easy workaround.